# PHP array_search bug?

Tags: php, arrays

I was trying to find a value in a multi-array variable.
It took too much time to find where was my bug...

Try this code:

```
$aa = array("nombre" => "HOLA", "v" => 0);
$bb = array("nombre" => "HOLB", "v" => 0);
$cc = array("nombre" => "HOLC", "v" => 0);
$dd = array($aa,$bb,$cc);

if (in_array("HOLA",array_column($dd,"nombre")))
     echo "in_array = yes";
else
     echo "in_array = no";

echo "<br>";

if (array_search("HOLA",array_column($dd,"nombre")))
     echo "array_search = yes";
else
     echo "array_search = no";
```

the answer I get is:

```
in_array = yes
array_search = no
```

It is this a supposed behavior?

Comment: Yes, it is expected behaviour; because it's finding the value at key 0, which you're then testing for truthinesss, and 0 == false. Use `if (array_search("HOLA",array_column($dd,"nombre")) !== false)`

Answer (score 2):

Yes. The documentation for [array_search](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-search.php) states the following:

> Warning: This function may return Boolean FALSE, but may also return a non-Boolean value which evaluates to FALSE. Please read the section on Booleans for more information. Use the === operator for testing the return value of this function.

The value you are getting is **0**, which is failing your `if`, but is the correct answer.

Answer (score 1):

`array_sarch` will return the index at which it finds the result, so in your case `'HOLA'` is at the `0` index which makes the condition fail.
You should check it like this

```
if (array_search("HOLA",array_column($dd,"nombre")) !== false)
```